# SwiperReact: Style navigation arrows in NextJs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

I created a slider with Swiper React Components in NextJs, but the navigation prop when set to "true" renders some ugly blue arrows that I would like to style.
To style my components I use makeStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles" and I apparently can't import css files in my components, unless it's my custom _app.js.
Is there a way I can style the navigation in NextJs?

Answer (score 1):

You can make your custom navigation and reference it via refs inside Swiper's navigation (or other) property.

```
<div className="pokerGames__navigation">
        <div className="arrow arrow-prev" ref={navigationPrevRef}></div>
        <div className="arrow arrow-next" ref={navigationNextRef}></div>
      </div>
      <Swiper
        navigation={{
          prevEl: navigationPrevRef.current,
          nextEl: navigationNextRef.current,
        }}
      >
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.